# How can I use an already instantiated class object inside of another method in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, constructor, instantiation

I have created the constructor and instantiated my menu class and called the display object from that class. (below)

```
public class App
    {
        //Create field
        private User _mainUser;
        
        public App()
        {
            //Instantiate the menu class
            Menu menu = new Menu();

            //Call Menu object's Init
            menu.Init("Main Menu", "Login", "About", "Exit");

            //call Menu objects Display method
            menu.Display();

            //Instantiate a new user and assign it to _mainUser
            _mainUser = new User();

            //Call the selection method
            Selection();
        }
```

Now, I am trying to use that same instantiated `menu.Display();` in another method in the same class. But it wants me to instantiate the Menu class again and then call the Display method.. again. But when I do that, my menu display isn't showing up. How can I use the same the menu.Display() that's in my constructor in another method shown below without instantiating it again?

```
private void Continue()
        {
            //Print out the continue message
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue... ");
            //Let the user hit a key
            Console.ReadLine();

            //Clear console
            Console.Clear();

            //Run menu class Display method
            //menu.Display(); <--- What i want to do but I cant

            //What its making me do but it won't show my menu because nothing is inside
            Menu menu = new Menu();
            menu.Display();

            //Run selection method
            Selection();
        }
```

Please help :)

****UPDATE******
I got the help I needed and the solution was easy enough *face palm*.
For others with this same question; With the help from these wonderful people, I just created a private `_menu` field and then declared it in my constructor. It worked beautifully. Code posted below bc I suck at explaining.

```
public class App
    {
        //Create field
        private User _mainUser;
        //Create a field for the menu class to access it throughout this entire class.
        private Menu _menu;
        
        public App()
        {
            //Instantiate the menu class
            _menu = new Menu();
           
            //Call Menu object's Init
            _menu.Init("Main Menu", "Login", "About", "Exit");

            //call Menu objects Display method
            _menu.Display();

            //Instantiate a new user and assign it to _mainUser
            _mainUser = new User();

            //Call the selection method
            Selection();
        }
```

Comment: Create Menu as an instance member, i.e. a *field*. `private Menu _menu` then you can access it anywhere in your class non static members

Comment: @00110001 Thank you so much! That worked like I needed it to.

Answer (score 1):

Same as `_mainUser`, create private member to keep same instance of the `Menu` class in the `App` class.

```
public class App
{
    private readonly User _mainUser;
    private readonly Menu _menu;
    
    public App()
    {
        _mainUser = new User();
        _menu = new Menu();

        _menu.Init("Main Menu", "Login", "About", "Exit");
        _menu.Display();

        Selection();
    }

    public void Continue()
    {
        _menu.Display();
    }
}
```

Comment: I attempted something similar thinking along those tracks but I couldn't quite get it lol. This worked great. Thank you so much!